# UTF-8 to HTML Character Decimal Codes before use inside code or importing in sql

Tags: php, sql, arabic, farsi

how can i detect and convert below strings to readable string this strings?

1. Ø³Ø¦ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø§Øª
2. Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø¹Ù† Ø§Ø¨ÙˆØ¨ÙƒØ±
3. Ù…Ø·Ø§Ø¹Ù† Ø¹Ù…Ø±

since these strings with `UTF-8` in `MySQL` database and our language is `Arabic` and `Persian` they are unreadable for us and I'm not sure how can we convert them to normal readable strings

sql table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  ...
  `title` longtext,
  `tblname` longtext,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=133 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

is there any online service or solution to convert them to readable strings before using them and importing into database?

we don't want to convert them inside `php` code with `iconv` or `convert` inside `sql`, we want to only convert them to have simple `sql` code before inserting into the database

Comment: How is PHP related? Do you set the charset on your db connection?

Comment: @this structure should be used with php, and we want to what are they in the first time before using them. they are unreadable in database too

Comment: How did you end up with `Ø³` in DB? Please add script and DB connection code. What should that be? It likely is lost because connection was set incorrectly.

Comment: @user3783243 this `sql` exported with `Navicat MySQL Data Transfer`, your mean is setting `charset` db connection was incorrect with that?

Comment: @DolDurma, Have you tried using `iconv` to convert between character sets?

Comment: You have a case of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) because you’ve mistreated encodings somewhere. Is it necessary to somehow fix this afterwards now, or can you simply fix your flow to treat encodings correctly along the way to avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: @deceze this `sql` is not our and we should fix `utf-8` before importing into the `mysql` database. we don't know how can we convert it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this online service resolve our problem, which with that we can convert `Unicode` to correct readable characters

[online service link](https://www.forgani.com/top/service/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysqli_set_charset() function before uploading/updating any string in database.

```
$conn = new mysqli(host,user,pass,dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");


// your query here
```

Comment: thanks but read again my question please